# android Swipe event in listview inside tab widget

Tags: android, view, viewflipper

I have created an Activity that shows a listview and on swipe action another list is shown using ViewFlipper. The code is attached below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    private Animation slideLeftIn;
    private Animation slideLeftOut;
    private Animation slideRightIn;
    private Animation slideRightOut;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private ListView lv;
    private String[] city = { "Indore", "Bhopal", "Khargone", "Ujjain",
        "Nasik", "Pune", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Noida", "Hyderabad",
        "Banglore", "Ajmer", "Goa", "Jaipur", "Nagpur", "" };
    private String[] country = { "India", "Bhutan", "Kuwait", "USA", };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List01);
        ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List02);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.slide_right_out);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city));
        lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });
        lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item List2 Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

It's working f9...

But when I place this within the another tab activity with the following code **The View Flipper is not working when placed as content(intent) in tab of another tabactivity (AppStart)**

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class AppStart extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    static Drawable myImage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        myImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.club);

        TabHost tabs = getTabHost();
        tabs.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec(null);

                Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
                spec = tabs.newTabSpec(null);
        spec.setContent(i);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

    }

}
```

The Layout is as follows:
main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/List01"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/List02" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

And main.xml as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Please suggest why the swipe gesture is not working when the same activity is placed in tab.

Thank You

Comment: While I haven't looked at your code nor specifically handled swipes with a similar layout, I can say the approach I'd take to figure this out would be to inspect the chain of onClick and onTouch handling through your entire layout, using logging and/or breakpoints, to understand what's handling what and when, i.e., in what order.  Then, I'd probably insert custom onClick and/or onTouch handling as appropriate to get the result I wanted.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  And I'd trace the dispatchTouchEvent calls.

Comment: what is flipBarBottom in the above code ?

Comment: flipBarBottom is a view on bottom of screen , that looks like a view with three dots. On view change the dots image get changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    private Animation slideLeftIn;
    private Animation slideLeftOut;

    private Animation slideRightIn;
    private Animation slideRightOut;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private ListView lv;

    private String[] city = {
        "Indore", "Bhopal", "Khargone", "Ujjain",
            "Nasik", "Pune", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Noida", "Hyderabad",
            "Banglore", "Ajmer", "Goa", "Jaipur", "Nagpur", ""
    };

    private String[] country = {
        "India", "Bhutan", "Kuwait", "USA",
    };


    @
    Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List01);
        ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List02);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.slide_right_out);

        ActivitySwipeDetector activitySwipeDetector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(
            this);

        //View on which gesture should function This is image view at bottom of listView on which flip gesture is performed.

        flipBarBottom.setOnTouchListener(activitySwipeDetector);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city));
        lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });

        lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item List2 Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

        static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
        private Activity activity;
        static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
        private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

        public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
            Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
            // activity.doSomething();
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
            viewFlipper.showNext();
            flipBarBottom.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flipstatus01);
        }

        public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
            Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            flipBarBottom.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flipstatus02);
            // activity.doSomething();
        }

        public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
            Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
            // activity.doSomething();
        }

        public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
            Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
            // activity.doSomething();
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    downX = event.getX();
                    downY = event.getY();
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    upX = event.getX();
                    upY = event.getY();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    float deltaY = downY - upY;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0) {
                            this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaX > 0) {
                            this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                    }
                    // swipe vertical?
                    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        // top or down
                        if (deltaY < 0) {
                            this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaY > 0) {
                            this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: is it possible to set the tab during swipe of the view. I mean i like to have swipe effect to change tabs. So is it possible with this ?

Comment: what is flipBarBottom in the above code. I am not able to swipe the screen

Comment: flipBarBottom is any view in that layout, say a view with the "..." we are changing the image so that if looks what is there with default home screens

Comment: yes u can modify the above code in that way,, onRightToLeftSwipe() and  onLeftToRightSwipe() need to be redefined (Say on this replace viewFlipper.next with the tab switch code) and your are done with

Comment: Your code only works for the changing view. But what about the activity ? I also want to change the View and respective activity while user do swipe.

Comment: Yes I can. But as per our earlier explaination, the view need not to to be switched . Activities need to be ( so you would ge gng with tabwidgets) now the tab widget child(say view , or intent i.e activity) need to be switched on the swipe event.

Comment: Sorry But not now. Because this question and answer was not meant to fulfill your current requirements.

Comment: Ok but you can do one thing update the code and put it in to the pastebin.com and give me a link of it.