# libgdx android style swipe

Tags: android, swipe, libgdx

How do i implement android style left and right swipe using libgdx? (ex:flipping through imgaes)

I read about GuesterDetector and testcase http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/GestureDetectorTest.java?r=2641.

But i am not sure once after guester identfied how to implement android style left and right swipe and also how to distinguish between left and right swipe with in fling method.

Implementing using adroid API is stright forward [android Swipe event in listview inside tab widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762554/android-swipe-event-in-listview-inside-tab-widget.I) understood admob example to implement native call backs, but integrating this seems not stright forward in this case.

Either way, Please let me know if some one experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

From that example, you are wanting to use the fling method. To detect horizontal direction, check the velocityX -- positive means a swipe to the right (and you'll want to scroll your images to the left).